# Java handler how to execute an intent without sending a onUserInteraction method

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to execute another intent from the main intent after some time, and when i close the other intent to reexecute the handler.

My problem is that after the second intent is executed for some reason the program thinks that its onUserInteraction method and it reexecutes the handler.

Main intent:

```
 handler = new Handler();
 r = new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 intent = new Intent(DataChecker.this, IdleImages.class);
 startActivity(intent);
     }
   };
 startHandler();
  }
    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUserInteraction();
        stopHandler();//stop first and then start
        startHandler();
    }
    public void stopHandler() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    }
    public void startHandler() {
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1*60*1000);
    }
```

Second Intent:

```
@Override
public void onSliderClick(SliderView sliderView) {
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 setResult(2, intent);
 finish();
}
```

When the second intent is closed it should restart the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by use two events `onResume()` and `onPause()`

```
    @Override
    public void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("Yes", "I stoped the handler for you");
        stopHandler();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("Back", "I started the handler for you");
        stopHandler();
        startHandler();
    }
```